# Display or link an image from a remote server without HTTP

Tags: html, image, href, remote-server

Need to be able to either use a link or display an image off a remote server that does not allow access over HTTP.

For example, I can type file://remoteserver/path/to/img.jpg in my address bar and the image will display, but none of these work:

```
<img src="//remoteserver/path/to/img.jpg" />
<img src="file://remoteserver/path/to/img.jpg" />
<a href="//remoteserver/path/to/img.jpg" />
<a href="file://remoteserver/path/to/img.jpg" />
```

Currently I have to just output file://remoteserver/path/to/img.jpg and have the user copy/paste into the address bar which is pretty bad. Preferably a cross-browser solution, but anything is better than what I have. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can't mix http  and file urls in a single page. that's a security restriction in browsers to prevent an "outside" page trying to load "local" content.

Comment: I figured it was a security issue, but I don't see why I can't even display an image off a remote server that all the users on that page have access to anyway? I don't need them to be downloaded or anything, just viewable.

Comment: viewable == downloaded - the file _must_ be downloaded to be viewed. It might not get _saved_ locally but it is downloaded.

Comment: Note that `file://remoteserver/path/to/img.jpg` works only because you are on a Windows network and the remote server shares the path.  This type of reference is meaningless if the server and client are not on the same network and not using Windows SMB sharing.

Comment: @Jim  Sorry for the incorrect semantics, but my point still stands that most sites have images displayed without it being a security risk and that's all I want to do.

Comment: @Jim The other users are all on the same network, if they were to type that in their browser it has the same result as mine. Hence why it's frustrating to not be able to provide the less tech-savvy with a link they can click to view :)

Comment: Then configure the remote server to serve the images over HTTP.  If there's no security risk then the server admin should not have a problem with it.  All this probably needs is a symbolic link to the directory in question, or a configuration change to place the image directory within the server hierarchy.  It's ultimately up to the owner of the server, and you have to convince them of the business case for it.